# How to find xpath for node value which also contains child node?

Tags: xml, xpath, word-addins

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<TEST xmlns="http://www.TEST.net/AMOD/CustomXML.htm">  
  <TESTTEST>Test
    <SEQNO1>1</SEQNO1>  
    <SEQNO2>2</SEQNO2> 
  </TESTTEST> 
</TEST>
```

How to get xpath for selecting the for Test inside the `<TESTTEST>` tag?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `/text()` to get child node of type text node :

```
//ns:TESTTEST/text()
```

(I assume you have `ns` prefix registered pointing to the default namespace URI)

Comment: I want output like this
<TESTTEST>Test</TESTTEST> without the child nodes

Comment: @SrinikethanRagupathi Modifying XML is not the job for XPath. You'll need to use some other tools (can be a programming language like C#,Python, .etc or sth else)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what do you mean exactly, but for instance

`/TEST/TESTTEST[contains(., 'Test') and ./SEQNO1]`

Comment: I want output like this
<TESTTEST>Test</TESTTEST> without the child nodes